# What's query string limit in node.js openurl and how to send email using default email client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailto

I'm using node.js for my desktop app. I need to send email from it. So I use the below code:

```
require("openurl").open("mailto:"+emailAddress+"?" + 
    "subject=TEST subject&" +
    "body=Hello! How are you?\nHello! How are you?\nHello! How are you?\nHello! " + 
    "How are you?\nHello! How are you?\nHello! How are you?\nHello! How are you?\n" +
    "Hello! How are you?\nHello! How are you?\nHello! How are you?\n");
```

This invokes the email client, but the email body text is truncated by around 200 characters.

I tried the below code also:

```
require("openurl").mailto(["john@example.com", "jane@example.com"],
        { subject: "Hello!", body: "This is\na generated email!\n" });
```

Reference link: https://github.com/rauschma/openurl

This code just adds the email id (first email) and nothing else (subject and email body doesn't get added).

Comment: What OS are you using? Works just fine on Mac OS X. If you don't need an actual e-mailclient, perhaps you can use `nodemailer` or `node-email` instead.

Comment: I'm using windows 7. I need to open mail in email client.

Comment: Please format your code you paste here. :-)

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: As per https://github.com/rauschma/openurl/blob/master/openurl.js#L50, you might have to pass a different separator to `mailto()` in your second example.

Comment: I tried but didn't succeed. Can you please paste an example?

Answer (score 1):

`openurl` is not meant to send email, this is meant to ask the OS to open the url in the most adapted app.  So `http` url would open in your default browser, and `mailto` will open in your mail app to compose the email.

To send an email from `node.js`, this question provides plenty of options: [Sending emails in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113701/sending-emails-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. Can you please tell me the query string limit in openurl? everything else is working for me and I just need to change the query string limit. Is it possible to change it?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the OS (256Kb for Mac), and windows appears to be 8Kb (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473/en-us).  Couldn't find if windows 7 had increased that limit.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. We'll check it.