# Nodemailer is giving error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, smtp, nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer for sending a forget password mail with Gmail service.I tried to reach to the same error earlier in the StackOverflow, but I couldn't find the solution. Please help me, I have no idea why it is giving error like,

> "TypeError: Cannot create property 'mailer' on string 'smtpTransport'"

Here is my code below-

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

app.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
          return res.redirect('/forgot');
        }

        user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
          done(err, token, user);
        });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
        console.log(token, "Token");
        console.log(user, "user")
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'abc@gmail.com',
          pass: '123456'
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'myproducts@mailinator.com',
        subject: 'My Products Password Reset',
        text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
          'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
          'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
          'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
        done(err, 'done');
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/forgot');
  });
});
```

And the error is something like this-

> /home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:132
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot create property 'mailer' on string 'smtpTransport'
>       at Mail (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:45:33)
>       at Object.module.exports.createTransport (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:52:14)
>       at /home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/app.js:185:38
>       at nextTask (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5310:14)
>       at next (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5317:9)
>       at /home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16
>       at /home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/app.js:177:11
>       at /home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3913:16
>       at model.$__save.error (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:342:7)
>       at /home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/kareem/index.js:297:21
>       at next (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/kareem/index.js:209:27)
>       at Kareem.execPost (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/kareem/index.js:217:3)
>       at _cb (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/kareem/index.js:289:15)
>       at $__handleSave (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:280:5)
>       at /home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:208:9
>       at args.push (/home/cis/Desktop/myproducts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:404:72)
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Possible duplicate 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414634/nodemailer-using-gmail-cannot-create-property-mailer-on-string-smtp

Comment: @abdulbarik, this duplicate question helped me to find the solution to this problem. 
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("smtps://youruser%40gmail.com:"+encodeURIComponent('yourpass#123') + "@smtp.gmail.com:465");

Answer (score 0):

The Nodemailer structure has been changed, try use this :

```
smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'Gmail', 
auth: {
xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
//and other stuff here
 });
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to follow your answer, but still didn't work. It is giving me another error, "Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
"

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
   service: "Yahoo",  // sets automatically host, port and connection security settings
   auth: {
       user: "xxxxxxxxxx95@yahoo.com",
       pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
   }
});

function mail(messageBody) {
    let messageBodyJson = JSON.stringify(messageBody)
    smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
        from: "xxxxxxxxxx95@yahoo.com", // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using Gmail.
        to: "xxxxxxxxxx95@gmail.com", // receiver
        subject: "Emailing with nodemailer", // subject
        text: messageBodyJson // body
     }, function(error, response){  //callback
        if(error){
           console.log("error",error);
        }else{
            console.log(response);
        }

     //    smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages.  Comment this line out to continue sending emails.
     });
}

 mail("your mail message");
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to follow your answer, but still didn't work. Giving the same error.

Comment: are you using gmail or yahoo ?

Comment: you have to go to yahoo mail , and there ''account setting" and enable "Allow apps that use less secure sign-in"

Comment: Thank you @yogesh, now it worked for me. Somehow my prime motto was to do it by Gmail service. :)

Comment: gmail also you can do but gmail doesn't allow loose app login so you have to go google developer console generate key and then use with any authentication module like "xauth".

Comment: U need to Enable Security for Apps: yahoo -> https://login.yahoo.com/account/security. gmail -> https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

[Link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48924916/3780481)

Gmail / Google app email service requires OAuth2 for authentication. PLAIN text password will require disabling security features manually on the google account.

To use OAuth2 in Nodemailer, refer: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/

Sample code:

```
var email_smtp = nodemailer.createTransport({      
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  auth: {
    type: "OAuth2",
    user: "youremail@gmail.com",
    clientId: "CLIENT_ID_HERE",
    clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
    refreshToken: "REFRESH_TOKEN_HERE"                              
  }
});
```