# Automatic emails from website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email, smtp

I got a request at work to create an SMTP server so that our website can sent automatic emails on daily/weekly basis. In simple - we have a website running on node.js and I need to give it an ability to automatically send emails based on time or/and other conditions.

Since I never worked in this direction (and I just got into this field) I decided to ask a question here, to see what you(experts) have to say in regards of this subject.

p.s I might have a wrong understanding of how this should run, so feel free to correct anything that I said.

Comment: Ok. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setting up a brand new smtp server and managing correct configuration, security, and most important, domain/ip reputation can be a real pain, I would suggest using a cloud service for this task to get you going faster.

A few of these services, some of them with free tiers are Amazon SMS, Mailgun, SendGrid and Mandrill. At least Mailgun has a API wrapper available for Node.JS.

Comment: Okay, I was also just informed that our organization has a team that can set up(or help set up such a server), but maybe I am failing to understand the logic behind it. All it does is allows sending emails with @custom extension - correct? How would I implement this to a website, presuming <mailto> will no longer be an option?

Comment: If you have a node.js project and want it to send emails using a custom smtp server, there are plenty of similar questions with good answers here on SO. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113701/sending-emails-in-node-js
and https://nodemailer.com/

Comment: ah, well I somehow missed that question, thank you.

Comment: Good to hear that you might have found a path to a solution. 
Please mark the question as answered if you are happy with the response. All the best.