# How to Change "To Email adress" in Email js integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email

I'm integration EmailJs with my mern stack application. Can I pass/change my To email address through code? Currently, it's sending an email to address on which I have made account of EmailJs. I want to send an email to address which I write on runtime.

```
const variables = {
    message_html: 'message',
    from_name:'name',
    reply_to: "email@gmail.com"
}

window.emailjs.send(
    'gmail',
    templateId,
    variables
).then(res => {
    console.log('Email successfully sent!')
})
// Handle errors here however you like, or use a React error boundary
.catch(err => console.error('Oh well, you failed. Here some thoughts on the error that occured:', err))
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, Could you develop a little bit what you are trying to achieve. What problem are you facing ?

Comment: I want to send email to user through my aplication , the problem is how can i set the receiver email adress? i am using reactJs

Comment: You need to show more code or to explain how you want to achieve this. Are you getting the user email from an input, from an API call ?

Comment: i am getting user email as input, i just need to what is the variable name of receiver adress, like i write "reply_to". how can i pass receiver email to emailjs.send () function

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is quite old, but if anyone in the future encounters the same problem, you can follow what worked for me.

Add {{to_email}} in your "To" input field in the template and pass the value to to_email from your code like this:

```
var templateParams = {
  name: "James",
  notes: "Check this out!",
  to_email: "test@gmail.com",
};

emailjs
  .send("service_ssgeqcv", "template_bbzcuzr", templateParams, {
    publicKey: "your public key",
    privateKey: "your private key",
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

No, EmailJS does not seem to support spamming arbitrary email addresses, you have to [Connect your own email service](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/user-guide/connecting-email-services/) to receive the emails.

Comment: there is no other way i can send email to my website users?

Comment: sure, from the backend - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113701/sending-emails-in-node-js or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python