# Contact responses sent to email

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am using `repl.it` to build my website, however, `repl.it` has a server named HTML/CSS/JS and it does not support PHP which is mainly used to submit contact responses to email. The website is built in the HTML/CSS/JS Server. So I cannot use PHP to submit contact responses to email. Is there an alternate way of doing it with Node.js?

I still have the PHP set up but it just needs to be converted to Node.js if that is possible.

### PHP File:

```
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['subject'];
if(empty($fname) || 
empty($lname) || 
empty($email_address) || 
empty($message)){
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}else{
//some other code 
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission:" . $name;
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: " . $name . "\n ".
"Email: $email_address\n Message \n " . $message;
$headers = "From:" . $myemail . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:" . $email_address;
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header('Location: thank-you.html');
}
```

### REST OF The CODE:

```css
input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: rgb(62, 3, 179);
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="contact.php" method="POST">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is there a way to translate the PHP code into Javascript, and whenever the user hits the submit button, the responses get sent to email? Any suggestions would greatly help. I tried changing it but I got stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending emails in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113701/sending-emails-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the xampp package (windows/linux) and start the apache server, so you can seamlessly run your PHP scripts.

Here's download link: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

If yours is Linux, it's also available to download.